# old-timey love duet played at end of Colorado radio show

Tags: radio

I'm looking for a song that was played at the end of an old-time radio show.  This was about 25 years ago.

This was in Denver area of Colorado.  I think the radio station was AM and up in the foothills.  It would play music from player pianos and carrousels/band organ as well as others.  Show was in the evening...not sure if daily or weekly.

The song featured a male and female singer.  It reminds me of "baby its cold outside" but I can't remember any lyrics.  But I think it was the couple just saying good night to one another.

The broadcaster mentioned a tremble in the female singer and equated it to her being nervous singing with the male singer.

Comment: Not a lot to go on, but as a guess : ["Two sleepy people"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ3bWueDhjM).  There are many versions.

Comment: @angst,  I'll have to try to remember more about the song.  Two sleepy people isn't it, unfortunately.  Thanks.